# Add a route for a screen, not in main Navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React Navigation to create a bottom bar navigation as document [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator#api-definition) (see code below).

```
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I have another Screen that I'd like to register without adding it to this `Tab.Navigator`, so that I can use `navigation.navigate("myOtherScreen")` somewhere else.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example worked for me, maybe it will work for you.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeStackScreen() {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator();

function SettingsStackScreen() {
  return (
    <SettingsStack.Navigator>
      <SettingsStack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      <SettingsStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </SettingsStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsStackScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

This example is in the documentation [here!](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation)

Comment: It's working. I also had to add `headerMode="none"` to avoid unnecessary header.

Comment: I am happy that is was useful for you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using `react-navigation` version 5.x:

You can use nested navigators similar to the following:

```
 function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
  }
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Tabs" component={MyTabs} />
            <Stack.Screen name="yourOtherScreen" component={OtherScreenComponent}/>
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      )}
```

You can read more about it in the official docs:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators

Comment: In my case, I don't want to be creating another NavigationContainer. I just want to be able to register some component / screen that I want to be able to link to.

Comment: As it stands with my example, there is only one `<NavigationContainer>`; where the Tabs 'screen' is nested inside the parent. I assume you define your own `<NavigationContainer>` somewhere, and the tab navigator you've shown actually is imported into the container at some point. If so, you can just put the new route in that container.

Comment: This example should work for you. This is what you need as per your question.